# Why is a second (or third, or ...) browser window being opened?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I've made a barebones setup to run Cucumber and Selenium in Java.

When I have one feature file `FirstScenario.feature` with its corresponding step definition `FirstScenarioSteps.java`, everything as expected. So I added a second combo, and that's when I noticed that a second browser window was opened, even when running only one scenario in the first feature file. So, I deleted the combo and everything was fine again. I found out that only the second step definition file (without the feature file) was enough to open that second browser window. I was curious so I added a third step definition file, and three browser windows got opened.

Why are there (in this case) three browser windows being opened per scenario? The last two windows opened remain blank (ie. do not navigate to a website).

Here's a step definition file.

```java
public class ThirdFeatureSteps {
    WebDriver driver;

    // Tests or no tests, browser windows are still opened.

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty(
            "webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
        );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I understand that @Before and @After are executed per scenario, and that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gaj Julije mentioned, hooks are global so all before hooks are executed before each feature.

You can solve this by using dependency injection. When using dependency injection Cucumber will try to create the constructor dependencies of your step definition classes. These dependencies are created as singletons so if two step definition classes have the same dependency they'll also get the same instance of that dependency.

This can be used to share information (or web drivers) between different step definition files or ensure that there is only a single web driver.

This is also better then using a `static` web driver. You can only run your tests in parallel if you don't modify any static variables.

Add the [cucumber-picocontainer](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer) dependency to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

Then create a container for the `WebDriver`:

```java
public class WebDriverContainer {
    public WebDriver webdriver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty(
            "webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
        );
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
       webdriver.quit();
    }

}
```

Then use the container in your step definitions.

```java
public class FirstFeatureSteps {
    WebDriverContainer container;

    public FirstFeatureSteps(WebDriverContainer container){
       this.container = container;
    }

    // use container.webdriver in your steps
}
public class SecondFeatureSteps {
    WebDriverContainer container;

    public SecondFeatureSteps(WebDriverContainer container){
       this.container = container;
    }

    // use container.webdriver in your steps
}
public class ThirdFeatureSteps {
    WebDriverContainer container;

    public ThirdFeatureSteps(WebDriverContainer container){
       this.container = container;
    }

    // use container.webdriver in your steps
}
```

But keep in mind that you can use `container.webdriver` in the constructor, the web driver will be `null` until the before-hook has ran.

Comment: 1. Should `driver` in `WebDriverContainer` be `webdriver`?

2. Where does the constructor of a steps class get its value from?

Comment: 1. Fixed. 2. Pico container can create the arguments, recursively as long as it will find a zero argument constructor eventually.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You are creating a new driver instance, and that is why you have three browser, and after you quit and open new.

If you do not want 3 instance, you will need to have browser initialize class and make global variable driver as static, also add get method in that initialize class, which will return your static web driver. Make sure that other classes inheret initialize class.

Than you can operate by creating only one browser instance.
Conclusion change @Before and @ After methods.

Comment: Won't I run into problems when using a static field when tests are going to be run in parallel?

Comment: You will. That's what dependency injection solves. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer