# Where do you put initialization tasks like reading a properties file etc when using Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

Although I have a working test suite, I'm still very new to the world of Java, Selenium and Cucumber. I've kind of inherited a project and most of it I've rewritten in a way that's maintainable and extensible. However, one thing still bothers me.

The program uses a certain class to initialize variables needed. It does the following things:

- Read variables from a properties file
- Validate those properties
- Exposes public static final variables for things like the host to test against, other urls needed, etc.
- Call Boni García's WebDriverManager setup which checks the version of the local browser and downloads a compatible webdriver

All these things either need only run once or are expensive. This class is a Singleton and I understand it only gets instantiated once. Sounded good to me, but then I read that Singletons in general are a bad idea.

Since Cucumber is an extension to Junit, there is no main(), at least not in this program and I haven't seen examples using it. So, what would be a good way to do those operations?

I read about DI, but then, I would need to pass this class to all classes that need access to these variables like the url of the site to test. Also, having WebDriverManager check browser version every time doesn't seem like a good idea.

I read about the static block, but how can I know this class is loaded first?

So, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are a pattern. And like all patterns they have advantages and disadvantages. You'll have to make the choice if those trade-offs are worth it. If not, you'll have to change the pattern.

And very generally speaking those trade-offs are not worth it. Unless you have a single expensive resource you should probably not consider using singletons at all. Dependency injection -with or without a framework- is usually the better way to go.

However you have a single expensive object. The Webdriver. So the singleton pattern is worth considering. And broadly speaking, if you do not intend to run your tests in parallel there is no reason not use a singleton pattern.

> I read about DI, but then, I would need to pass this class to all classes that need access to these variables like the url of the site to test. Also, having WebDriverManager check browser version every time doesn't seem like a good idea.
>
> I read about the static block, but how can I know this class is loaded first?

You can combine the Singleton pattern with lazy initialization. Rather then immediately creating the singleton as a static variable when the classes is loaded, you create an static getter method. When this method is called the first time you create the singleton instance and return it. When called a second time, you return the created singleton instance.

```java
private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver getWebDriver(){
  if (driver != null){
    return driver;
  }

  driver = // create driver here

  return driver;
}
```

> Since Cucumber is an extension to Junit, there is no main(), at least not in this program and I haven't seen examples using it. So, what would be a good way to do those operations?

You can use `cucumber-piccontainer` It's a very simple form of DI.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer

Comment: Hah, it's you again! There is parallel processing and I've followed your earlier advice (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943503/) which is working flawlessly and I can't thank you enough for that. Anyway, now I'm still not sure what to do in this case. It seems from your wording that using a Singleton is even worse when running tests in parallel (although I didn't run into problems, yet).

Comment: You can't run tests in parallel with a singleton that is mutable. For example multiple threads would try to make one single browser do different things all at once. 

If your singleton is immutable it doesn't matter because it can only be read from so parallel execution can do no harm.

But long story short: Create the webdriver multiple times. You can't avoid it so the cost of creating web drivers multiple times is irrelevant.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear. The webdriver IS being created multiple times using your code for which I've provided the link. It's just the setup() method (Boni García's WebDriverManager) that only needs to run once. The one that checks browser version, compares it to its cache, downloads it if necessary. That, and reading the properties file, setup the urls, etc.

Comment: Using picocontainer for this class means I have to put this class in every constructor of every method of my steps classes and page components. Is that the way to go? And then put reading of the properties file, all the initializations of variables, the webdriver setup() method in a static block to make it only execute once? Not the creation of the webdriver itself, that's handled by your code in a @before hook of WebDriverContainer. And then, all variables need to be prepended with this class name instead of just static importing them which looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Ah, I just checked. The Singleton is immutable so I guess I'm alright then. Like you said, it doesn't matter!

Comment: Great! For the long term, the cost of adding a constructor parameter everywhere is mostly tedium. But a few minutes of tedium beat hours of debugging a flakey system. You can also use Lombok to generate the constructors. If you don't mind occasionally debugging Lombok related problems.

Comment: Just wanted to say I did the whole shebang. Wasn't bad, actually, only took about 20 minutes. Recommended. 